# Determine the right parameters for deblurring motion blurred images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, motion

I'm currently working on program and I need to automatic perform motion un-blurring on a picture.  Currently, I make a `for` loop for `LEN` and `THETA`, guessing from `LEN` `0:50` and `THETA` from `1:180`. There are plenty of motion un-blurred pictures produce in this way - some correct and some are wrong. Now here is my problem: How do I actually determine which set of parameters yields the one most closest to original photo?

I'm thinking of using pixel comparison. Any idea on this?

Here's a pictorial example of what I generated:

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81112742/Capture.JPG

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the original clean image, I would compute the [Peak Signal to Noise Ratio (PSNR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio) for all of the images you have generated, then choose the one with the **highest PSNR**.  [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro) posted a very nice post on how to compute this for images and can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16265510/3250829

However, for self-containment, I'll post the code to do it here.  Supposing that your original image is stored in the variable `I`, and supposing your reconstructed (un-blurred) image is stored in the variable `K`.  Therefore, to calculate the PSNR, you would need to calculate the [Mean Squared Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) first, then use it to calculate the PSNR.  In other words:

```
mse = mean(mean((im2double(I) - im2double(K)).^2, 1), 2);
psnr = 10 * log10(1 ./ mean(mse,3));
```

The equations for MSE and PSNR are:

[image]

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio)</sup>

---

As such, to use this in your code, your `for` loops should look something like this:

```
psnr_max = -realmax;
for LEN = 0 : 50
    for THETA = 1 : 180
        %// Unblur the image
        %//...
        %//...
        %// Compute PSNR
        mse = mean(mean((im2double(I) - im2double(K)).^2, 1), 2);
        psnr = 10 * log10(1 ./ mean(mse,3));
        if (psnr > psnr_max) %// Get largest PSNR and get the
            LEN_final = LEN; %// parameters that made this so
            THETA_final = THETA;
            psnr_max = psnr;
        end
    end
end
```

---

This loop will go through each pair of `LEN` and `THETA`, and `LEN_final`, `THETA_final` will be those parameters that gave you the best reconstruction (un-blurring) of the image.

Comment: If I don't have the original image, then this method cannot be done? My actual project is images with different theta and Len will be given then need to automatic unblur it

Comment: @chrischiang Without a reference image, I can't think of any method that will allow you to choose the most optimum settings to unblur your image.  There are metrics that measure quality without a reference image, but those are still in major experimentation and are highly subjective.  I can't give you a good answer here.