# PSNR of image using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I want to find out PSNR and SNR values of two images A and B of same dimension in Matlab.I used the following code

```
[peaksnr, snr] = psnr(A,B)
```

and getting an error

```
Undefined function 'psnr' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
```

Then I converted both the images into double as follows

```
A = double(A);
B = double(B);
```

and again PSNR is calculated.Now I'm getting an error

```
Undefined function 'psnr' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Why this is happening?Please help me to troubleshoot the error.

Comment: What version of Matlab do you use? `psnr` seems to a be a recent addition

Comment: Personally, I think this is a better way to compute PSNR for images: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16265510/3250829

Comment: what about     [peaksnr, snr] = psnr(uint8(A), uint8(ref));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
         function PSNR = psnr(distImg, origImg)

            origImg = double(origImg);
            distImg = double(distImg);

            [M N] = size(origImg);
            error = origImg - distImg;
            MSE = sum(sum(error .* error)) / (M * N);

            if(MSE > 0)
            PSNR = 10*log(255*255/MSE) / log(10);
            else
            PSNR = 99;
            end 

        end
```

Comment: Why do you assign a `PSNR` of 99 if the MSE is negative?  By definition, the mean **squared** error will never be negative.  Also the `log(10)` division is incorrect.  Consult the definition of the PSNR here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio

Comment: Hi in matlab when error occurs MSE is negative thus PSNR=99 is maximum. Also base of log function in matlab is 2 and this formula is correct.Because log(a)/log(b)=log(a) in base b.

Comment: Ah yes, ok.  What you should do is use `log10`.  It avoids having to divide in order to get it into the right base.  However, the MSE will **NEVER** be negative.  Sum of squared errors was created to circumvent any negative deviation, so that I don't agree with.  The arbitrary 99 is not correct either IMHO.  I looked at the PSNR source in MATLAB, and there is no -99 assignment anywhere.

Comment: BTW the base of the log function is **e**, not 2.  `log2` is the function that is base 2.  Please read up about MATLAB internals before answering any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
psnr = 10*log10(255/sqrt(mean((image1(:) - image2(:)).^2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some mistakes with above code where it should consider log10 in Matlab.
So the correct code (even for color image) is as below:

```
function PSNR = MyPsnr(distImg, origImg)
        origImg = double(origImg);
        distImg = double(distImg);

        [M N P] = size(origImg);
        error = origImg - distImg;
        MSE = sum(sum(sum(error.^2))) / (M * N * P);

        if(MSE > 0)
            PSNR = 20*log10(max(max(max(origImg))))-10*log10(MSE);
        else
            PSNR = 99;
        end
```

Comment: what's differnce of log10(2)/log10(8) with log2(2)/log2(8)